# My references have an indent after the 7th natbib item

Tags: bibtex, natbib

As to be seen in the picture there is an indent because I use natbib. If I use ordinary bib instead I do not get this, but then I am not able to use `citet()`.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[square,numbers,nonamebreak]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\setlength\bibhang{0pt}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\raggedright}

\newcommand\tab[1][1.2cm]{\hspace*{#1}}\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{placeins}
%\usepackage[font=12p,labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}


%\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\center 
\textsc{\LARGE University of Amsterdam}\\[1cm]
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Pic/UvA.jpg}\\[1cm]
\textsc{\Large MSc. Econometrics}\\[0.5cm] 


{ \LARGE \bfseries Master Thesis}\\[0.4cm] 
%\HRule \\[1cm] 
\textsc{\LARGE  The performance of the Netflix prize winning model on music data.} \\[1cm]

Supervisor:     Kevin Pak\\
Student: Joshua Jones, 10757597\\
{\large \today  \\ [2cm]}
\begin{abstract}
\input{Abstract.tex}    
\end{abstract}
\large\textbf{}\\[2cm]

\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents{}
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\input{Indroduction.tex}

\section{Related Work}
\subsection{Basics of Collaborative Filtering}
\input{Relatedwork/CollaborativeFiltering.tex}




\section{Data}
\input{Data.tex}
\section{Methodology}



\subsection{Overview of estimated models}
\input{Methodology/Overview.tex}
\input{Methodology/Baseline.tex}



%\subsection{Netflix models}
\input{Methodology/Netflix.tex}

\subsection{Improved model}
\input{Methodology/Improved.tex}

\section{Results}
\input{Results.tex}

\section{Conclusion}
\input{Conclusion.tex}

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{References}

\clearpage
\appendix
\section*{Appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
%\appendixpage
%\addappheadtotoc

\input{appendix.tex}


 \end{document}
```

This was the main file which calls the references file which is below:

```latex
@article{negativesim,
 author               = {Ying Liu and Jiajun Yang},
 doi                  = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.procs.2015.07.164},
 issn                 = {1877-0509},
 journal              = {Procedia Computer Science},
 keywords             = {Recommendation system, Ranking-based recommendation, Collaborative filtering},
 note                 = {3rd International Conference on Information Technology and Quantitative Management, ITQM 2015},
 pages                = {732 - 740},
 title                = {Improving Ranking-based Recommendation by Social Information and Negative Similarity},
 url                  = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050915016397},
 volume               = {55},
 year                 = {2015},
 }


@inbook{AdvancesinCollaborativeFiltering,
 author               = {Koren, Yehuda and Bell, Robert},
 doi                  = {10.1007/978-1-4899-7637-6_3},
 isbn                 = {978-1-4899-7636-9},
 month                = {01},
 pages                = {77-118},
 title                = {Advances in Collaborative Filtering},
 year                 = {2015},
 }
@inproceedings{Boltzmann,
 author               = {Salakhutdinov, Ruslan and Mnih, Andriy and E. Hinton, Geoffrey},
 doi                  = {10.1145/1273496.1273596},
 journal              = {ACM International Conference Proceeding Series},
 month                = {01},
 pages                = {791-798},
 title                = {Restricted Boltzmann machines for collaborative filtering},
 volume               = {227},
 year                 = {2007},
 }
@inproceedings{MSD1,
  author = {Thierry Bertin-Mahieux and Daniel P.W. Ellis and Brian Whitman and Paul Lamere},
  title = {The Million Song Dataset},
  booktitle = {{Proceedings of the 12th International Conference on Music Information
    Retrieval ({ISMIR} 2011)}},
  year = {2011},
  owner = {thierry},
  timestamp = {2010.03.07}
}

@misc{echo,
    title = {The Echo Nest Taste profile subset, the official user data collection for the Million Song Dataset},
    author = {{The Echo Nest}},
    howpublished={\url{http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/tasteprofile}},
    note = {Retrieved on: 10.04.2019}
}

@MISC{TheBellkorSolution,
    author = {Robert M. Bell and Yehuda Koren and Chris Volinsky},
    title = {The BellKor solution to the Netflix Prize},
    year = {2007}
}

@misc{Echo2,
    title = {The Echo Nest company website, available at:},
    author = {{The Echo Nest}},
    howpublished={\url{http://the.echonest.com/company/}},
    note = {Retrieved on: 10.04.2019}
}

@misc{Kaggle,
    title={Million Song Dataset Challenge, the Kaggle challenge, available at:},
    author = {Kaggle},
    howpublished={\url{https://www.kaggle.com/c/msdchallenge}},
    note = {Retrieved on: 10.04.2019}
}
@misc{MSD2,
    title={The Echo Nest company website, available at:},
    author = {Thierry Bertin-Mahieux},
    howpublished={\url{http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong}},
    note = {Retrieved on: 10.04.2019}
}
@misc{NetflixPrize,
    title={The Netflix Prize Official Website, available at:},
    author = {Netflix},
    howpublished={\url{https://www.netflixprize.com/index.html}},
    note = {Retrieved on: 10.04.2019}
}
@misc{Johnson,
    title = {Algorithmic music recommendations at spotify, available at:},
    author = {Chris Johnson},
    howpublished={\url{http://www.slideshare.net/MrChrisJohnson/algorithmic-music-recommendations-at-spotify/}},
    note = {Retrieved on: 10.04.2019}
}

@article{Sanchez,
 author = {S\'{a}nchez-Moreno, Diego and Gil Gonz\'{a}lez, Ana B. and Mu\~{n}oz Vicente, M. Dolores and L\'{o}pez Batista, Vivian F. and Moreno Garc\'{\i}a, Mar\'{\i}a N.},
 title = {A Collaborative Filtering Method for Music Recommendation Using Playing Coefficients for Artists and Users},
 journal = {Expert Syst. Appl.},
 issue_date = {December 2016},
 volume = {66},
 number = {C},
 month = dec,
 year = {2016},
 issn = {0957-4174},
 pages = {234--244},
 numpages = {11},
 url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.eswa.2016.09.019},
 doi = {10.1016/j.eswa.2016.09.019},
 acmid = {3006098},
 publisher = {Pergamon Press, Inc.},
 address = {Tarrytown, NY, USA},
 keywords = {Collaborative filtering, Data mining, Gray-sheep, Music recommendation, Sparsity},
} 

@inproceedings{Sarwar,
 author = {Sarwar, Badrul and Karypis, George and Konstan, Joseph and Riedl, John},
 title = {Item-based Collaborative Filtering Recommendation Algorithms},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 10th International Conference on World Wide Web},
 series = {WWW '01},
 year = {2001},
 isbn = {1-58113-348-0},
 location = {Hong Kong, Hong Kong},
 pages = {285--295},
 numpages = {11},
 url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/371920.372071},
 doi = {10.1145/371920.372071},
 acmid = {372071},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
} 

@inproceedings{Grouplens,
 author = {Resnick, Paul and Iacovou, Neophytos and Suchak, Mitesh and Bergstrom, Peter and Riedl, John},
 title = {GroupLens: An Open Architecture for Collaborative Filtering of Netnews},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 1994 ACM Conference on Computer Supported Cooperative Work},
 series = {CSCW '94},
 year = {1994},
 isbn = {0-89791-689-1},
 location = {Chapel Hill, North Carolina, USA},
 pages = {175--186},
 numpages = {12},
 url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/192844.192905},
 doi = {10.1145/192844.192905},
 acmid = {192905},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {Usenet, collaborative filtering, electronic bulletin boards, information filtering, netnews, selective dissemination of information, social filtering, user model},
}

@article{Herlocker,
 author = {Herlocker, Jonathan L. and Konstan, Joseph A. and Terveen, Loren G. and Riedl, John T.},
 title = {Evaluating Collaborative Filtering Recommender Systems},
 journal = {ACM Trans. Inf. Syst.},
 issue_date = {January 2004},
 volume = {22},
 number = {1},
 month = jan,
 year = {2004},
 issn = {1046-8188},
 pages = {5--53},
 numpages = {49},
 url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/963770.963772},
 doi = {10.1145/963770.963772},
 acmid = {963772},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {Collaborative filtering, evaluation, metrics, recommender systems},
} 

@inproceedings{Paterek,
  title={Improving regularized singular value decomposition for collaborative filtering},
  author={Arkadiusz Paterek},
  year={2007}
}

@article{leedaniel,
 author               = {Lee, Daniel and Seung, Hyunjune},
 journal              = {Adv. Neural Inform. Process. Syst.},
 month                = {02},
 title                = {Algorithms for Non-negative Matrix Factorization},
 volume               = {13},
 year                 = {2001},
 }

@article{xinzhou,
  author    = {Xin Luo and
              MengChu Zhou and
              Shuai Li and
              Mingsheng Shang},
  title     = {An Inherently Nonnegative Latent Factor Model for High-Dimensional
              and Sparse Matrices from Industrial Applications},
  journal   = {{IEEE} Trans. Industrial Informatics},
  volume    = {14},
  number    = {5},
  pages     = {2011--2022},
  year      = {2018},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1109/TII.2017.2766528},
  doi       = {10.1109/TII.2017.2766528},
  timestamp = {Sat, 24 Nov 2018 00:00:00 +0100},
  biburl    = {https://dblp.org/rec/bib/journals/tii/LuoZ0S18},
  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, https://dblp.org}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{KDD,
    author = {Robert M. Bell and Yehuda Koren and Chris Volinsky},
    title = {Modeling relationships at multiple scales to improve accuracy of large recommender systems},
    booktitle = {Proc. KDD’07},
    year = {2007}
}

@article{HALS,
 author               = {Kim, Jinguand He, Yunlongand Park, Haesun},
 issn                 = {1573-2916},
 journal              = {Journal of Global Optimization},
 month                = {Feb},
 number               = {2},
 pages                = {285--319},
 title                = {Algorithms for nonnegative matrix and tensor factorizations: a unified view based on block coordinate descent framework},
 url                  = {https://doi.org/10.1007/s10898-013-0035-4},
 volume               = {58},
 year                 = {2014},
 }

@article{NALS,
 author               = {Kim, H. and Park, H.},
 doi                  = {10.1137/07069239X},
 eprint               = {https://doi.org/10.1137/07069239X},
 journal              = {SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications},
 number               = {2},
 pages                = {713-730},
 title                = {Nonnegative Matrix Factorization Based on Alternating Nonnegativity Constrained Least Squares and Active Set Method},
 url                  = {https://doi.org/10.1137/07069239X},
 volume               = {30},
 year                 = {2008},
 }

@inproceedings{NSVDalgorithm,
 author               = {Takács, Gábor and Pilászy, István and Németh, Bottyán and Tikk, Domonkos},
 doi                  = {10.1109/ICADIWT.2008.4664342},
 journal              = {1st International Conference on the Applications of Digital Information and Web Technologies, ICADIWT 2008},
 month                = {09},
 pages                = {186 - 191},
 title                = {A Unified Approach of Factor Models and Neighbor Based Methods for Large Recommender Systems},
 year                 = {2008},
 }
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please post code, not a screenshot, no-one if going you type this in in order to test your issue. We will also need the bib file. (3) You may want to clean up your preamble as you are loading several packages multiple times.

Comment: From the screenshot it is indeed hard to guess the solution, but maybe changing `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` might help (and removing `numbers` from the `natbib` options)?

Comment: I have added the code for the main and for the references

Comment: @Marijn, thanks, but those suggestions did not help

Comment: I can't reproduce. But I added `\usepackage{url}` in order not to get errors due to underscores in the DOI.

Comment: Fix the 14 errors reported by the little red square - i'm sure the problem will vanish